Crystal Report: How to use the Operator 'in' with if conditions
I added this crystal report formula but it does not proceed and displayed an error instead.
Please see the below for reference.
enter image description here
"
If {?@btype} = "All"
then {Sp_StockEndingInventory_Batches;1.BATCH_TYPE_} in ('BATCHED', 'NON-BACTHED')
else {?@btype}={?@btype}={Sp_StockEndingInventory_Batches;1.BATCH_TYPE_}
"
Any ideas? Thanks in advance.
I tried to change the quotes from single to double but it still doesn't work.

Try this instead:
{?@btype} = "All" OR {?@btype}={Sp_StockEndingInventory_Batches;1.BATCH_TYPE_}


Hello @MilletSoftware, I tried using that but I need to indicated the field values 'BATCHED' and 'NON-BATCHED'. Any other idea? Thank you

If the only 2 possible values are 'BATCHED' or 'NON-BACTHED' then the solution I suggested above should work as-is.
If there are other possible values, then use:
(
  {?@btype} = "All" AND 
  {Sp_StockEndingInventory_Batches;1.BATCH_TYPE_} in ('BATCHED', 'NON-BACTHED')
)
OR 
{?@btype}={Sp_StockEndingInventory_Batches;1.BATCH_TYPE_}


Hi @MilletSoftware. I tried your first and second solution and now it's working perfectly. I just put the formula in the Reports > Select Expert. Thank you!
